# How to solve the error in uploading an image in level 2 deeper model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## Models in my app

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dishes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assets_attributes
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dish
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "640x480", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

## In Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
gem 'paperclip'
```

## app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @dish = @category.dishes.new(:category_id => params[:id])
    @dish.assets.build    
    @title = "Create dish"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @category }
    end
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @dish = @category.dishes.create(params[:dish])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { 
        flash[:success] = "Dish created successfully!"
        redirect_to(@category) }
      format.json  { render :json => @category }
    end
  end

end
```

## app/views/categories/show.html.erb

```
<p><%= notice %></p>

<h1> Category Details </h1>

...

<hr />

<h2>Dishes</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>

  <%= render @category.dishes %>

</table>

<%= link_to 'New Dish', newdish_path(:id => @category.id) %>
```

## app/views/dishes/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Dish</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

## app/views/dishes/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@category, @dish]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...# Here the fields for dishes table will come
  <div class="field">
    <h4>New Files</h4>
      <% f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
        <% if asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <p>
        <%= asset_fields.file_field :asset %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <h4>Old Files</h4>
      <% f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>          
        <% unless asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <div class="thumb">
        <%= link_to image_tag(asset_fields.object.asset.url(:thumb)), asset_fields.object.asset.url(:original) %>
        <%= asset_fields.check_box :_destroy %>         
      </div>    
    <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
...
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

While trying to run these code I got an error

```
SyntaxError in Dishes#new

Showing /home/ragunathjawahar/Desktop/PROJECT/karaikudi-before-send/app/views/dishes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

/home/ragunathjawahar/Desktop/PROJECT/karaikudi-before-send/app/views/dishes/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
...r([@category, @dish]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f...
...                               ^
/home/ragunathjawahar/Desktop/PROJECT/karaikudi-before-send/app/views/dishes/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
...ml => { :multipart => true } do |f| @output_buffer.safe_conc...
...                               ^
/home/ragunathjawahar/Desktop/PROJECT/karaikudi-before-send/app/views/dishes/_form.html.erb:51: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The question title doesn't really explain the problem you are having.  Maybe edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this line first and tell

```
    <%= form_for([@category, @dish], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

use this line for create dish

```
            @dish = Dish.create!(:dishCode => params[:dish][:dishCode] ,:name => params[:dish][:name])
```

instead of

```
        @dish = @category.dishes.create(params[:dish])
```

but first check  params[:dish][:dishCode] give you value or not.

And chill.......

Comment: Hi Kashif ali, Now the image is uploading properly, but the data in the fields in dishes table were not saved in the database

Comment: Can you please puts params[:dish] and check its populated with form valued you are entering.

Comment: I got the values by puts params[:dish] but not saved in database

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7nF4131hw8Mt/M4ykvZpanLCHXfinJT9ncyfywcGYvk=", "dish"=>{"dishCode"=>"S04", "name"=>"sam", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"asset"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xab887d8 @original_filename="kuberppsingle.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dish[assets_attributes][0][asset]\"; filename=\"kuberppsingle.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120413-23636-10uf8da>>}}, "cookingTime"=>"10", "available"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Create Dish", "category_id"=>"1"}

Comment: use this line instead of   @dish = @category.dishes.create(params[:dish])

Comment: I used the line you said the data passed in params but a warning... WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: dishCode, name, description, price, cookingTime, available
  AREL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "dishes" ("dishCode", "name", "description", "price", "image", "cookingTime", "available", "category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-04-13 08:59:09.287159', '2012-04-13 08:59:09.287159')

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @dish]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @dish], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

i.e., you are closing the bracket too early.

Comment: Hi Kristianp, Now the image is uploading properly, but the data in the fields in dishes table were not saved in the database